# Can a single source of code be ran universally after each Selenium test or test run?

Tags: c#

I am curious if there is a capability in Visual Studios 2012/2013 using C# and Selenium to have a universal bit of code run for a project or solution after each Test completes (or each batch of tests).

The opposite is useful as well, running code in the initialization phase of a test.

I know that each test class has the ability to run a [SetUp] or [TearDown] method, but I was curious if there was a repository elsewhere that runs this code for all tests without defining it in each class.

Comment: This is not a Selenium question. The SetUp and TearDown functionality is provided by the test framework (e.g NUnit) not Selenium. Without providing the name of the framework you use, no one is able to provide a solution.

Comment: The framework we are using is Selenium.

Comment: Selenium is not a framework.  Are you using a testing framework?

Comment: I don't understand the question. I was always told the frameworks include Selenium, Coded UI, Telerik, etc.

Comment: Selenium and CodedUI are libraries which allow you to interact with a web page.  They are not the framework which provides the ability to define and run tests.  Test frameworks make uses of Selenium to create UI tests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a base class for all of your tests and decorate it with the appropriate attributes for your testing framework of choice. Then have all of your test classes inherit that class.

Comment: This sounds like a good option. This might add some extra work to replace current inheritance, but I could certainly do this.